# Generating simulated data based on a formula

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
d<- structure(list(groupid = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), participant_id = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 
45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L), 
    attrib1_A = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0), attrib1_B = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -134L), groups = structure(list(
    participant_id = 1:50, .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:5, 6:8, 
        9:11, 12:14, 15:17, 18:20, 21:22, 23:25, 26:28, 29:31, 
        32:33, 34:36, 37:39, 40:42, 43:44, 45:47, 48:49, 50:52, 
        53:55, 56:58, 59:61, 62:63, 64:66, 67:68, 69:71, 72:73, 
        74:76, 77:79, 80:81, 82:84, 85:87, 88:89, 90:92, 93:95, 
        96:98, 99:101, 102:104, 105:107, 108:110, 111:113, 114:116, 
        117:119, 120:121, 122:123, 124:125, 126:128, 129:130, 
        131:132, 133:134), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
# Groups:   participant_id [4]
   groupid participant_id attrib1_A attrib1_B
     <int>          <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1       2              1         0         1
 2       2              1         1         0
 3       2              1         0         0
 4       1              2         0         0
 5       1              2         1         0
 6       2              3         1         0
 7       2              3         0         0
 8       2              3         0         1
 9       2              4         0         1
10       2              4         1         0
```

My aim is to generate a simulated dependent variable `Y`. `Y` is a dummy taking only two values 1 and 0. I would like the dummy to be created with a using a Bernoulli distribution around the following true data generating process:

$y=a+factor(attrib1_A)+ factor(attrib1_B)$. `attrib1_A` and `attrib1_B`are my key regressor of interest.

Where *a* is the constant: the probability of y=1 when `attrib1` and `attrib2` correspond to reference categories. The betas are attrib1_A= 0.3 attrib1_B= -0.5.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first block wouldn't run for me, but the exercise is straight forward.
In the following code, I just create two factors with the specified effects, then use the `arm::invlogit` to create probabilities which can be passed through to the binomial.

```
n <- 1e5
b1 <- .3 
b2 <- -.5 
a <- as.factor(rbinom(n, 1, .5))
b <- as.factor(rbinom(n, 1, .5))
probs <- arm::invlogit(b1*a + b2*b)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, prob = probs)

dat <- data.frame(a,b,y)
m1 <- glm(y ~ a + b, data =dat, family = binomial)
summary(m1)

# 
# Call:
#   glm(formula = y ~ a + b, family = binomial, data = dat)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -1.3056  -1.0828  -0.9662   1.1759   1.4045  
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  0.003637   0.010994   0.331    0.741    
# a            0.292889   0.012811  22.862   <2e-16 ***
#   b           -0.523197   0.012812 -40.835   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
# Null deviance: 138336  on 99999  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 136141  on 99997  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 136147
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this: it is really helpful. I have a question. Do you know how i could create this accounting for some intercluster correlation (ICC) between outcomes of participants of the same group?

Comment: I have adjusted the first block: it would work now!

Comment: glad it worked for you! I'm not sure I understand, you want to simulate clusters? Can you post another question?